# Add Existing Animation

Tags: unity, animation, loading

I have several animations that I am using on a GameObject.  I switched the folder they were stored in, and they got detached from the gameObject.  How can I add the existing animations to my gameObject without having to recreate them?

I am not looking to do this programmatically.  I just want to undo the damage I have done without having to start over.  Ideally, I want a "Load Animation" option from the Animator window in the editor, but that does not appear to exist :-/.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I fixed the same issue:

1. Open the animator window
2. Click on the game object that has the animation
3. In the animator window for that game object, the original animations you set should still be there. Click on one of them.

[image: animator window]

4. In the inspector, there is a property called "Motion" where the animation from your new animation folder should be. Drag and drop it there and it should start working the same as you had it before.

[image: inspector window]

Answer (score 2):

Just drag the animator controller that has your animations in it to the Animator on your game object you should be able to access your animations again.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to build rebuild the Animator from the saved Animations

Comment: not sure what you named yours but it will look like the example image above. drag that to your animator and when you access the gameobject that has the animator you can now see your saved animations you made in the animations tab

Comment: I just accidentally deleted the player object and this helped me reapply the animations without having to redo them all. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add existing animations to a new animator controller on your game object but don't have the older animation controller for some reason? If so, drag and drop the existing animations onto the new animation controller in the animator window. You will have to create parameters and transitions again.
If you have the old animation controller just drag and drop it onto the game object in the inspector, it will have all existing transitions and animation states.